# getting a value along with html markup returned by Ajax in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following to retrieve some html using Jquery:

index.php

```
$.post(
    'get-products.php', 
    $("#offerForm").serialize() + '&lastid=' + highest, 
    function(data) {            
        $('#demo').html(data); 
    }
```

Is it possible to also retrieve a value of a variable from get-products.php, example:

get-products.php

```
<? echo $htmlOutput;
echo $variable; ?>
```

index.php

```
$.post(
    'get-products.php', 
    $("#offerForm").serialize() + '&lastid=' + highest, 
    function(data) {
        $('#demo').html(data);
        //variable processing statement goes here   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to communicate in JSON.
This way in get-products.php you can return an array json encoded containing your html, some variables
and then in jquery you'll get data.variable1, data.variable2, etc...

Do it by calling post with a third parameter ("json")
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
  $.post(
        'get-products.php', 
        $("#offerForm").serialize() + '&lastid=' + highest, 
        function(data) {            
            $('#demo').html(data.html); 
            variable1 = data.variable1;
        }
```

And in get-products.php return

```
echo json_encode(array('html' => '<div>some html</div>', 'variable1'=>xxxx));
```

Comment: parameter dataType is not necessary btw, but it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

yes you could, use json for that. Example:

```
<?php
$html = "<p>some html</p>";
$data = array('key' => 'value');
$output = json_encode(array('html' => $html, 'data'=>$data));
echo $output;
?>
```

Now in jquery retrieve the data like:

```
function(data) {
    $('#demo').html(data.html);
    // and do something with data.data
    alert(data.data.key); // alerts "value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead return JSON from your `get-products.php` page, like this:

```
<?
    $arr = array('htmlOutput' => $htmlOutput, 'otherVariable' => $variable);
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$.post(
    'get-products.php', 
    $("#offerForm").serialize() + '&lastid=' + highest, 
    function(data) {
        $('#demo').html(data.htmlOutput);
        var x = data.otherVariable;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you set as url a local path on the, that the js request is not understanding in a request, because it is running local on your system.

simple replace the 'get-products.php' with an url like http://yourhomepage.com/get-products.php

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the best option, but if for some reason you're unable to implement this, you could set a data attribute on the outer element in the html returned, and then read it using `jQuery.data()`.

html

```
<div class="response-outer" data-variable-name="value">
 ...
</div>
```

NOTE: the data attribute will be automatically parsed by jQuery and if it is in JSON format will be converted into a javascript object

jQuery

```
$.post(
    'get-products.php', 
    $("#offerForm").serialize() + '&lastid=' + highest, 
    function(data) {
        $('#demo').html(response);
        var x = $("#demo").find(".response-outer").data("variable-name");
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do that, depending on your data. They are all based on the same concept: Add your data to the DOM.

You can return a hidden input with some value in it:

```
<input id=data-object type=hidden value=myvalue />
```

This works for single, small values.

You can add the data to the relevant DOM elements:

```
<div id=some-div custom-value=myvalue>
```

that way you can attach extra info to specific elements around the DOM

You can add a Javascript object inside a script tag, and access it with client code:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
var myData = {attribute: value, someObject:{anotherAttribute: value}};
</script>
```